# React native app not working after installing from Play store

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-play

I have developed a react native application, everything works fine, APK, shared and distributed, I am able to install it on all devices also.

But when I am downloading from the play store. Nothing happens after clicking App ICON.
I have attached logs also, I am not sure what this error is all about.

React Native Info

```
React native Info:
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: Windows 7 6.1.7601
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 2.58 GB / 7.90 GB
Binaries:
Node: 12.19.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 6.14.8 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
SDKs:
Android SDK:
API Levels: 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
Build Tools: 21.1.2, 23.0.2, 25.0.0, 25.0.1, 25.0.3, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3
System Images: android-22 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
Android NDK: 21.0.6113669
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version 3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Thanks in advance

```
    2021-10-15 14:28:15.933 1501-1765/? I/DropBoxManagerService: add tag=system_server_wtf
isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
2021-10-15 14:28:16.140 2774-4696/? I/chatty: uid=1001(radio) Thread-8 identical 2 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:16.342 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:16.525 1501-2168/? D/MIUIInput: [MotionEvent] publisher action=0x4, 79022220, channel '566128b NavigationBar (server)'
2021-10-15 14:28:16.526 1501-2168/? D/MIUIInput: [MotionEvent] publisher action=0x4, 79022220, channel 'b4e434e StatusBar (server)'
2021-10-15 14:28:16.526 1501-2168/? D/MIUIInput: [MotionEvent] publisher action=0x0, 79022220, channel '4b5002 com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity (server)'
2021-10-15 14:28:16.543 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:16.545 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag truestateRESUMED
2021-10-15 14:28:16.546 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 2
2021-10-15 14:28:16.546 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:16.546 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:16.550 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.550 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:16.550 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.551 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag truestatePAUSING
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 1501-1738/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 3
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:16.552 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag falsestatePAUSING
2021-10-15 14:28:16.553 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 3
2021-10-15 14:28:16.550 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for GameOptimization
2021-10-15 14:28:16.555 974-1007/? D/ANDR-PERF-LM: Feature: lookup() 101: Feature Name = AppClassifier, total featuers = 4, featureFound = 1
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? D/ANDR-PERF-LM: Feature: getData() 112: data.data = 1
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for GameOptimization returned
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for GameOptimization
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? D/ANDR-PERF-LM: Feature: lookup() 101: Feature Name = AppClassifier, total featuers = 4, featureFound = 1
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? D/ANDR-PERF-LM: Feature: getData() 112: data.data = 0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for GameOptimization returned
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:16.556 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.564 1501-4505/? D/MIUIInput: [FoucsChange]: Display  0 FocusedWindow From null(0,0)  to Window{4b5002 mode=1 rootTaskId=4747 u0 com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity}(1,1)
2021-10-15 14:28:16.585 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.598 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 1 line
2021-10-15 14:28:16.615 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.623 1501-2168/? D/MIUIInput: [MotionEvent] publisher action=0x1, 79022318, channel '4b5002 com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity (server)'
2021-10-15 14:28:16.632 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.646 21842-21842/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:79022342
2021-10-15 14:28:16.647 1313-2290/? W/iorapd: Overwriting transition from kActivityLaunched to kIntentStarted into kActivityLaunchCancelled
2021-10-15 14:28:16.648 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.648 1501-1738/? D/EventSequenceValidator: IntentStarted during UNKNOWN. Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 

    pkg=com.tuktukautos.drive cmp=com.tuktukautos.drive/.MainActivity }
        java.lang.Throwable: EventSequenceValidator#getStackTrace
            at com.google.android.startop.iorap.EventSequenceValidator.logWarningWithStackTrace(EventSequenceValidator.java:260)
            at com.google.android.startop.iorap.EventSequenceValidator.onIntentStarted(EventSequenceValidator.java:106)
            at com.android.server.wm.LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.handleOnIntentStarted(LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.java:139)
            at com.android.server.wm.LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.lambda$veRn_GhgLZLlOHOJ0ZYT6KcfYqo(Unknown Source:0)
            at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$LaunchObserverRegistryImpl$veRn_GhgLZLlOHOJ0ZYT6KcfYqo.accept(Unknown Source:10)
            at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:292)
            at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
            at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:45)

2021-10-15 14:28:16.648 1501-1738/? D/EventSequenceValidator: inc AccIntentStartedEvents to 69
2021-10-15 14:28:16.648 1501-4505/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.tuktukautos.drive cmp=com.tuktukautos.drive/.MainActivity} from uid 10189
2021-10-15 14:28:16.649 1501-4505/? D/MiuiMultiWindowAdapter: MiuiMultiWindowAdapter::getFreeformBlackList::sSmallWindowBlackList = [com.miui.securitycenter, com.miui.weather2, com.miui.miservice, com.android.calendar, com.xiaomi.calendar, com.android.contacts, com.miui.mishare.connectivity, com.android.settings, com.android.printspooler, com.miui.backup, com.miui.huanji, com.miui.calculator, com.android.deskclock, com.android.thememanager, com.mfashiongallery.emag, com.miui.virtualsim, com.miui.smarttravel, com.mi.health, com.android.camera, com.lbe.security.miui, com.miui.cleanmaster, com.miui.newhome, com.miui.voiceassist, com.android.phone, com.miui.yellowpage, com.android.updater, com.miui.tsmclient, com.miui.securitycore, com.xiaomi.account, com.xiaomi.shop, com.mipay.wallet, com.xiaomi.youpin, com.xiaomi.hm.health, com.miui.bugreport, com.xiaomi.mibrain.speech, com.xiaomi.mimoji, com.xiaomi.scanner, com.duokan.phone.remotecontroller, com.miui.hybrid, com.android.incallui, com.miui.video, com.miui.videoplayer, com.miui.player, com.miui.fm, com.miui.packageinstaller, com.mi.android.globallauncher, com.google.android.dialer, com.google.android.apps.magazines, com.miui.compass, com.miui.greenguard, com.kiteguard, com.google.android.apps.prodcasts, com.google.ar.lens, com.xiangkan.android, com.android.bankabc, com.sohu.inputmethod.sogou, com.tencent.mtt, com.shyz.toutiao, com.netease.mc.mi, com.outfit7.talkingtomgoldrun.mi, com.doudz.mi, com.wepie.snake.new.mi, cn.jj, com.standddz002.mi, com.miHoYo.bh3.mi, com.qqgame.hlddz, com.happyelements.AndroidAnimal, com.minitech.miniworld.TMobile.mi, com.mfp.jelly.xiaomi, com.lilithgames.afk.mi, com.tencent.peng, com.teenpatti.hd.gold, blockpuzzle.jewelgames.jewelslegend, com.playgendary.tanks, com.chillingo.robberybobfree.android.row, com.episodeinteractive.android.catalog, com.playrix.township, com.ansangha.drdriving, com.google.android.youtube, com.gbits.atm.mi]
2021-10-15 14:28:16.650 1501-4505/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag falsestateINITIALIZING
2021-10-15 14:28:16.650 1501-4505/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag truestateINITIALIZING
2021-10-15 14:28:16.650 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.651 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.661 1501-4505/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.661 1501-4505/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 440
2021-10-15 14:28:16.661 1501-4505/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.665 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.673 1313-2290/? W/iorapd: Rejecting transition from kActivityLaunchCancelled to kActivityLaunched
2021-10-15 14:28:16.673 1501-1738/? D/EventSequenceValidator: onActivityLaunched during UNKNOWN.
    java.lang.Throwable: EventSequenceValidator#getStackTrace
        at com.google.android.startop.iorap.EventSequenceValidator.logWarningWithStackTrace(EventSequenceValidator.java:260)
        at com.google.android.startop.iorap.EventSequenceValidator.onActivityLaunched(EventSequenceValidator.java:149)
        at com.android.server.wm.LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.handleOnActivityLaunched(LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.java:157)
        at com.android.server.wm.LaunchObserverRegistryImpl.lambda$UGY1OclnLIQLMEL9B55qjERFf4o(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$LaunchObserverRegistryImpl$UGY1OclnLIQLMEL9B55qjERFf4o.accept(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:292)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:45)
2021-10-15 14:28:16.681 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.681 1501-4505/? D/MIUIInput: [FoucsChange]: Display  0 FocusedWindow From Window{4b5002 mode=1 rootTaskId=4747 u0 com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity}(1,0)  to null(0,0)
2021-10-15 14:28:16.698 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.715 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 1 line
2021-10-15 14:28:16.731 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.743 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:16.748 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.916 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 10 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:16.932 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:16.944 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:16.950 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.045 1501-1738/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{f1b0120 u0 com.tuktukautos.drive/.MainActivity t4750}
2021-10-15 14:28:17.055 1501-1738/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{f1b0120 u0 com.tuktukautos.drive/.MainActivity t4750}
2021-10-15 14:28:17.055 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag truestatePAUSED
2021-10-15 14:28:17.057 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag falsestatePAUSED
2021-10-15 14:28:17.033 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 5 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:17.051 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.057 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 4
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag truestateRESUMED
2021-10-15 14:28:17.057 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 4
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 2
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for GameOptimization
2021-10-15 14:28:17.058 974-1007/? D/ANDR-PERF-LM: Feature: lookup() 101: Feature Name = AppClassifier, total featuers = 4, featureFound = 1
2021-10-15 14:28:17.059 974-1007/? D/ANDR-PERF-LM: Feature: getData() 112: data.data = 0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for GameOptimization returned
2021-10-15 14:28:17.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:17.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.061 1501-1738/? V/ActivityTaskManager: Calling mServicetracker.OnActivityStateChange with flag falsestateRESUMED
2021-10-15 14:28:17.062 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: Activity state is changed to : 2
2021-10-15 14:28:17.064 811-827/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10364[I] (10)0x30000->*launch*[S] 
2021-10-15 14:28:17.066 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.070 1501-1738/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:79022766
2021-10-15 14:28:17.145 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:17.146 23377-23377/? W/adbd: timeout expired while flushing socket, closing
2021-10-15 14:28:17.347 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:17.548 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:17.564 2316-2905/? D/MobileSignalController: updateDataType mSelectedDataTypeIcon[1]=2131233177, mSelectedDataActivityIndex=7
2021-10-15 14:28:17.565 2316-2905/? D/TelephonyIcons: getSignalStrengthIcon: slot=1, inetCondition=1, level=2, roaming=false, signalstrength=SignalStrength:{mCdma=CellSignalStrengthCdma: cdmaDbm=2147483647 cdmaEcio=2147483647 evdoDbm=2147483647 evdoEcio=2147483647 evdoSnr=2147483647 miuiLevel=0 level=0,mGsm=CellSignalStrengthGsm: rssi=2147483647 ber=2147483647 mTa=2147483647 miuiLevel=0 mLevel=0,mWcdma=CellSignalStrengthWcdma: ss=2147483647 ber=2147483647 rscp=2147483647 ecno=2147483647 miuiLevel=0 level=0,mTdscdma=CellSignalStrengthTdscdma: rssi=2147483647 ber=2147483647 rscp=2147483647 miuiLevel=0 level=0,mLte=CellSignalStrengthLte: rssi=-77 rsrp=-111 rsrq=-15 rssnr=4 cqi=2147483647 ta=2147483647 miuiLevel=2 level=2 parametersUseForLevel=0,mNr=CellSignalStrengthNr:{ csiRsrp = 2147483647 csiRsrq = 2147483647 csiSinr = 2147483647 ssRsrp = 2147483647 ssRsrq = 2147483647 ssSinr = 2147483647 miuiLevel = 0 level = 0 parametersUseForLevel = 0 },primary=CellSignalStrengthLte}
2021-10-15 14:28:17.565 2316-2905/? D/TelephonyIcons: getDataActivity, slot=1, activity=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.571 2316-2905/? D/TelephonyIcons: null signal icon name: drawable/stat_sys_signal_null
2021-10-15 14:28:17.573 2316-2905/? D/TelephonyIcons: getDataTypeIcon sub=1
2021-10-15 14:28:17.576 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.591 1501-3042/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:79023287
2021-10-15 14:28:17.604 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 5 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:17.605 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.749 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:17.950 1501-1765/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
2021-10-15 14:28:17.950 1501-1765/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2021-10-15 14:28:17.960 1501-1765/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 23549:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a99 (adj 985): empty #17
2021-10-15 14:28:17.951 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:17.972 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:17.972 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:17.972 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.972 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:17.972 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.972 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for PreKill
2021-10-15 14:28:17.973 1501-1765/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 23394:com.google.android.cellbroadcastreceiver/u0a243 (adj 985): empty #18
2021-10-15 14:28:17.973 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for PreKill returned
2021-10-15 14:28:17.973 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:17.973 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.975 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:17.975 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:17.975 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.975 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:17.975 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.975 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for PreKill
2021-10-15 14:28:17.976 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for PreKill returned
2021-10-15 14:28:17.976 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:17.976 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.980 1501-3042/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.980 1501-3042/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 440
2021-10-15 14:28:17.980 1501-3042/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
2021-10-15 14:28:17.982 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: startService() is called for servicecom.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentIntentOperationService
2021-10-15 14:28:17.985 1501-2191/? I/MiuiNetworkPolicy: updateUidState uid = 10108, uidState = 19
2021-10-15 14:28:17.985 1501-2191/? I/MiuiNetworkPolicy: updateUidState uid = 10076, uidState = 19
2021-10-15 14:28:18.014 1501-4479/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.014 1501-4479/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 440
2021-10-15 14:28:18.014 1501-4479/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.015 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: startService() is called for servicecom.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedService
2021-10-15 14:28:18.019 1501-4479/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.019 1501-4479/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 440
2021-10-15 14:28:18.019 1501-4479/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.021 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: startService() is called for servicecom.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for PreKill
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 813-813/? I/Zygote: Process 23549 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for PreKill returned
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:18.029 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.031 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: killProcess is called for pid : 23549
2021-10-15 14:28:18.032 6001-16503/? I/com.xiaomi.xms: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION and parcel size 0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.034 1501-1773/? I/libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10099 pid 23549 in 61ms
2021-10-15 14:28:18.039 1501-2191/? I/MiuiNetworkPolicy: removeUidState uid = 10099
2021-10-15 14:28:18.053 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: destroyService is called for service : com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedService
2021-10-15 14:28:18.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: LMPerfGlue: perfmodule_submit_request() 132: perfmodule_submit_request()
2021-10-15 14:28:18.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: getInstance() 84: LM getInstance
2021-10-15 14:28:18.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 59: LMTriggerQ push() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.058 974-974/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: push() 61: LMTriggerQ push() done size=1
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 813-813/? I/Zygote: Process 23394 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 42: LMTriggerQ pop() done size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 381: Calling runAsync for PreKill
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 391: runAsync for PreKill returned
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: Core: lmMain() 373: Waiting on trigger Queue
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 974-1007/? I/ANDR-PERF-LM: WQ: pop() 31: LMTriggerQ pop() size=0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.059 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: killProcess is called for pid : 23394
2021-10-15 14:28:18.060 6001-16503/? I/com.xiaomi.xms: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION and parcel size 0
2021-10-15 14:28:18.062 1501-2191/? I/MiuiNetworkPolicy: removeUidState uid = 10243
2021-10-15 14:28:18.062 1501-1773/? I/libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10243 pid 23394 in 27ms
2021-10-15 14:28:18.151 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:18.355 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:18.513 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: unbindService is called for service : com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentDirectBootAwareApiService and for client com.google.android.gms
2021-10-15 14:28:18.556 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:20.972 2774-4696/? I/chatty: uid=1001(radio) Thread-8 identical 12 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:21.174 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:21.239 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: unbindService is called for service : com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentDirectBootAwareApiService and for client com.google.android.gm
2021-10-15 14:28:21.240 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: size of service connections for service: com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentDirectBootAwareApiServiceafter removal is 8
2021-10-15 14:28:21.240 981-5162/? I/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.2-service: size of client connections for client: com.google.android.gmafter removal is 3
2021-10-15 14:28:21.374 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:22.074 1501-1738/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:79027770
2021-10-15 14:28:22.075 1501-1738/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_stopped time:79027771
2021-10-15 14:28:21.776 2774-4696/? I/chatty: uid=1001(radio) Thread-8 identical 2 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:21.977 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:22.079 2316-2316/? D/EventBus: [2316, u0] send(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
2021-10-15 14:28:22.103 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:22.146 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 3 lines
2021-10-15 14:28:22.162 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:22.178 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
2021-10-15 14:28:22.180 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:22.197 2316-2316/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) com.android.systemui identical 1 line
2021-10-15 14:28:22.214 2316-2316/? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0
2021-10-15 14:28:22.379 2774-4696/? I/SarService: Receiver polling >>>> Change receiver mode: off
```

Comment: does your app works on variant release . try doing some logcat first on the variant release